# Swift Generic Not Convertable

Tags: swift, generics

I have a generic value protocol,

```
protocol GenericValue {
    var abs: Self { get }
}
```

And I have a type, `Real` that implements this.

```
struct Real {
    let value: Double
}

extension Real: GenericValue {
    var abs: Real { return Real(value: abs(value)) }
}
```

I then have a container. For now, it only includes `Real`, but later, it will have more (but every value will conform to `GenericValue`).

```
enum Container {
    case real(Real)
}
```

I want to make `Container` conform to `Generic`, but use the `GenericValue` methods where possible.

```
extension Container {
    func map<T:GenericValue>(_ transform: (T) -> T) -> Container {
        switch self {
            case .real(let value):
                return .real(transform(value))
        }
    }

    var abs: Container { map { $0.abs } }
}
```

I get the error,

```
'((Real)) -> T' is not convertible to '(T) -> T'
```

Comment: The error happens because your `map` method is only generic over one type `T`. You can only ever call a version of `map` that works for one specific `T`, not for every possible type that could be associated with your enum cases. To elegantly solve your problem you'd need to be able to declare all associated values as conforming to `GenericValue`, and then have your `transform` block be a `(GenericValue) -> GenericValue`. The former requires a language feature that Swift doesn't have, the latter doesn't work, because `GenericValue` requires `Self`. A well known pain point.

Comment: I known this isn't very helpful. Your only real option would be to write out the implementation of `abs` by hand and add to it when you add more cases. It's tedious but that way `Container` can conform to `GenericValue`.